# Cuál es la diferencia en el significado, entre el Imperfecto, el Pretérito Indefinido + el Gerundio y el Imperfecto + el Gerundio?

Tags: gramática, pretérito-imperfecto, pretérito-perfecto, gerundio

Ejemplos:

> Yo te esperaba.
>
> Yo te estuve esperando.
>
> Yo te estaba esperando.

Cuál es la diferencia en el significado?

Answer (score 2):

- El pretérito imperfecto suele usarse para *acciones rutinarias* o *acciones que se repetían* en el pasado. En muchos casos, es equivalente al "used to" inglés

  > Cuando iba a la universidad, te esperaba todos los días en la estación para ir juntos
- La construcción (pretérito imperfecto de *estar*) + (gerundio) se utiliza para hablar de una acción en el pasado que *se extendió en el tiempo* y que *fue interrumpida por otra acción*. En muchos casos, equivale al *past continuous* ("I was doing") inglés:

  > Te estaba esperando en la estación cuando me llegó la noticia

  En algunos casos, el pretérito imperfecto también se usa con este significado. Esto ocurre sobre todo cuando la acción extensa viene introducida por el adverbio *mientras*

  > Mientras te esperaba en la estación, me llegó la noticia
- La construcción (pretérito perfecto simple de *estar*) + (gerundio) indica una acción en el pasado que se extendió en el tiempo, pero no fue interrumpida for otra acción:

  > Te estuve esperando dos horas en la estación

  Muchas veces, esta construcción se puede sustituir por el pretérito perfecto simple ("Te esperé dos horas en la estación"). La diferencia es que la oración con (pretérito perfecto simple de estar) + (gerundio) enfatiza más el hecho de que la acción se extendió en el tiempo.